# creating object with dynamic name JS

Tags: javascript

How can I accomplish this task:

```
var i = 'foo';
var x = {
          i: 'bar'
        }
console.log(x);
> {'foo':'bar'};
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```
var i = 'foo';
var x = {};
x[i] = 'bar';
```

Comment: thanks, I had to have some kind of eclipse of my mind and I could not come up with this by my own!